# How to properly prefix and suffix double quotes?

Tags: linux, shell, batch-file

**My Issue** : File does not get deleted because of spaces in path.

**What I tried to do** : Prefix " at start and end of path manually.  It works.  But, I am not able to do programatically.

**Present Code**

```
su
destination_path="/mnt/sdcard/abc/cde/"
mkdir -p $destination_path
mv /mnt/sdcard/location.ini $destination_path
cd $destination_path
while read line
do
    path=/mnt/sdcard/$line/
    rm $path/*
done < location.ini
```

**Location.ini** looks like

```
DCIM/Camera/
abc/cde efg/hij/kl/mn op/
```

**What I am looking for :**
Code to ensure all directories mentioned in Location.ini is deleted.

**Details :**
To be run in android console (shell)

Comment: Double quote the variables: `rm "$path"/*`

Comment: I tried a lot of things, nothing seemed to work.  I re wrote the code in python and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd actually use `sed` for this instead of double-quoting the string:

```
su
destination_path="/mnt/sdcard/abc/cde/"
mkdir -p $destination_path
mv /mnt/sdcard/location.ini $destination_path
cd $destination_path
while read line
do
    path = `echo $line | sed s/\ /\\\\\ /`
    path = /mnt/sdcard/$path
    rm $path/*
done < location.ini
```

The backticks force the code to be executed and the result placed in the `path` variable.

Answer (score 0):

To do it programically, enclose `$line` in quotes as

```
path="/mnt/sdcard/$line"
rm="$path"/*
```

To test this,

```
$mkdir Test\ this
$cat input 
Test this
$while read line; do cd $line; done < input 
bash: cd: Test: No such file or directory
$while read line; do cd "$line"; done < input 
$pwd
/home/xxx/Test this
```